# Debugging an Office.js desktop add-in: Where is the shortcut menu for the add-in

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

Following last section of [this Official tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio.md) on debugging an `Office.js Add-in`, talks about the `Reload` button on the shortcut menu of the add-in during `debug mode of an Office.js Add-in project` in `VS2017`. But I do not find that `Reload` button during debug mode after I click the add-in menu in the `MS WORD` ribbon as shown in the screenshot below. **Question**: Where is that Reload button located?

Last paragraph of the article: **Modify code and continue to debug the add-in without having to start the project again**:

```
You can change your code and review the effects of those changes in your add-in without having to close the host application and start the project again. After you change and save your code, open the shortcut menu for the add-in, and then choose Reload.
```

**Screenshot of my WORD document during debug mode in VS2017**:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Suggestion from `@Rick Kirkham` worked. Don't click the upside down triangle that is next to the `X` symbol on the top right corner of the Task Pane; instead, just click anywhere on the task pane and an arrow head pointing to the left will appear, and clicking on that arrow will show the `Reload` button.
**screenshot of my task pane add-in in WORD**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper right corner of the add-in's task pane, there is a small rectangle with an arrow head pointing to the left. This is the shortcut menu that it is talking about. You may have to click in that corner to make it visible.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I had to click on the top right corner of the task pane (as you had suggested).